How do I override ID_INPUT_MOUSE in a udev rule?
I am attempting to force wayland to not discover my 3dconnexion SpaceMousePro as a pointing device.  These docs on libinput in wayland  (section: "Device type assignment via udev") indicate that I should be able to do this via a udev rule.
I have attempted the following rule:
SUBSYSTEM=="input", ATTRS{idVendor}=="046d", ATTRS{idProduct}=="c62b", ENV{ID_CLASS}="joystick", ENV{ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK}="1" ENV{ID_INPUT_MOUSE}="", SYMLINK+="input/spacemousepro"

and have tested both with removal/reinsertion, udevadm trigger, and even a total power-off/power-on, but even though my ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK setting is honored and even though my ID_CLASS setting is also honored, the ID_INPUT_MOUSE field continues to be set as 1:
  $   udevadm test $(udevadm info -q path -n /dev/input/event31) 2>&1 | egrep ID_INPUT\|ID_CLASS
ID_CLASS=joystick
ID_INPUT_JOYSTICK=1
ID_INPUT=1
ID_INPUT_MOUSE=1

Is there something wrong in my syntax or is there some other confounding factor I'm unaware of?
